# Time complexity of following function

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

In the following C++ function, let n >= m.

```
int gcd(int n, int m) {
            if (n%m ==0) return m;
            if (n < m) swap(n, m);
            while (m > 0) {
                n = n%m;
                swap(n, m);
            }
            return n;
    }
```

What is the time complexity of the above function assuming n > m?
Answer to this question is O(log n), but I am not getting how it is calculated?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen swap is just a normal function to swap values

Comment: @dexter Thanks...I have suspected this but as I'm not a C++ person I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on each iteration, the value of `n` reduces by a factor of the golden ratio on average. I suggest trying to work out the worst case and it should be about log base 1.618 of `n`

For more details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm which notes "If the Euclidean algorithm requires N steps for a pair of natural numbers a > b > 0, the smallest values of a and b for which this is true are the Fibonacci numbers F(N+2) and F(N+1), respectively."

e.g. If you start with Fib(n+2) and Fib(n+1) you will get Fib(n) and Fib(n+1) on the next iteration until you stop at 1.

Comment: sorry I didn't get it. How am I supposed to think about using fibonacci on seeing above function?

Comment: @dexter In the worst case you have two Fibonacci numbers e.g. 21 and 13, when you do 21 % 13 you get 8 which is the previous fibonacci number, 13 % 8 is 5, the previous one, 8 % 5 is 3 the previous one and 5 % 3 = 2 finally 3 % 2 == 1.

Answer (score 0):

First consider these two possibilities for `while` loop:

1. In the loop given below, the complexity of this loop is `O(n)`
   because the algorithm grows in proportion to its input n:

   ```
   while (n > 0) {
       n = n-1;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Whereas in the loop given below, since there's a nested loop, the
   time would be `O(n^2)`.

   ```
   while(n>0) {
       n = n-1;
       while(m>0) {
           m = m-1;
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. However, in the algorithm which you've provided, you aren't
   traversing the loop for every `m` or `n`; instead, you are simply
   using divide-and-conquer approach, and you're exploring only portion
   of entire `n` in your loop. On each iteration, the value of `n`
   isn't reducing by just a factor of `1`, but a bigger ratio:

   ```
   while (m > 0) {
       n = n%m;
       swap(n, m);
   }
   ```